# Text Extraction from JSON using C# in Window Forms

Tags: c#, json, winforms, .net-core

I am working with OXFORD DICTIONARY API which gives meaning to a word. It returns the result in JSON format and hence I want to extract only the meaning of the word from the JSON. I am using the C# NEWTONSOFT package but am unable to get the output. The code and output screenshot I attached below any help is highly appreciated.

```
using System;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string word_id = " ";
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a word : ");
        word_id= Console.ReadLine();
        const string lang_code = "en-gb";
        const string fields = "definitions";
        const string strictMatch = "false";
        string WEBSERVICE_URL = "https://od-api.oxforddictionaries.com:443/api/v2/entries/" + lang_code + '/' + word_id + "?fields=" + fields + "&strictMatch=" + strictMatch;
        try
        {
#pragma warning disable SYSLIB0014 // Type or member is obsolete
            var webRequest = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(WEBSERVICE_URL);
#pragma warning restore SYSLIB0014 // Type or member is obsolete
            if (webRequest != null)
            {
                webRequest.Method = "GET";
                webRequest.Timeout = 12000;
                webRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
                webRequest.Headers.Add("app_id", "xxxxxxx");
                webRequest.Headers.Add("app_key", "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx");

                using System.IO.Stream s = webRequest.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
                using System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(s);
                var jsonresponse = sr.ReadToEnd();
                var jdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<details>(jsonresponse);
                Console.WriteLine("Meaning : ", arg0: jdata.results.lexicalEntries.entries.senses.definitions);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }

        
    }
}

public class details
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    public results results { get; set; }
    public string word { get; set; }

}

public class Metadata
{
    public string? operation{ get; set; }
    public string? provider { get; set; }
    public string? schema{ get; set; }
}

public class results
{
    public string? id { get; set; }
    public string? language { get; set; }
    public lexicalEntries lexicalEntries { get; set; }
    public string? type { get; set; }
    public string? word { get; set; }
}

public class lexicalEntries
{
    public entries entries { get; set; }
}

public class entries
{
    public senses senses { get; set; }
}

public class senses
{
    public string definitions { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

[Output for above code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eT4ym.png)

JSON OUTPUT:

```
{
    "id": "necrosis",
    "metadata": {
        "operation": "retrieve",
        "provider": "Oxford University Press",
        "schema": "RetrieveEntry"
    },
    "results": [
        {
            "id": "necrosis",
            "language": "en-gb",
            "lexicalEntries": [
                {
                    "entries": [
                        {
                            "senses": [
                                {
                                    "definitions": [
                                        "the death of most or all of the cells in an organ or tissue due to disease, injury, or failure of the blood supply."
                                    ],
                                    "id": "m_en_gbus0682990.005"
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    ],
                    "language": "en-gb",
                    "lexicalCategory": {
                        "id": "noun",
                        "text": "Noun"
                    },
                    "text": "necrosis"
                }
            ],
            "type": "headword",
            "word": "necrosis"
        }
    ],
    "word": "necrosis"
}
```

Comment: Hard to say without actual JSON (if you can attach it, it will be very helpful), but according to exception, it seems that `results` property in `details` class should be an array-type - try changing type of `results` property to `results[]`.

Comment: sure why not let me attach the json format as well

Comment: Have you considered taking the JSON result and running it through a generator, like https://json2csharp.com/

Answer (score 1):

Your main issue is not using an array or List when trying to deserialize an array from the json.

Until you're more familiar with JSON deserialization, I especially recommend using [json2csharp.com](https://json2csharp.com/) or something similar to generate classes for you. You can also just use it as a starting point, but you take your json result, paste it in, and there's all the classes you need to make it work. I generally rename the Root class it generates and have named it Details below.

Whenever you see `"property": [ ]` with the brackets like that, it means it's an array of whatever is inside, so your corresponding property in C# has to be defined as an array or List.

```
  public class Metadata
{
    public string operation { get; set; }
    public string provider { get; set; }
    public string schema { get; set; }
}

public class Senses
{
    public List<string> definitions { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
}

public class Entry
{
    public List<Senses> senses { get; set; }
}

public class LexicalCategory
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class LexicalEntry
{
    public List<Entry> entries { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public LexicalCategory lexicalCategory { get; set; }
    public string text { get; set; }
}

public class Result
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string language { get; set; }
    public List<LexicalEntry> lexicalEntries { get; set; }
    public string type { get; set; }
    public string word { get; set; }
}

public class Details
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Metadata metadata { get; set; }
    public List<Result> results { get; set; }
    public string word { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this actually worked,
the problem was with the deserializing of the JSON object, the initial object was an array that needed to be treated as an ITem or ICollection object:

{ var jdata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Item<details>>(jsonresponse);}

Comment: Also the Newtonsoft.Json package and System.Text.Json namespace were overlapping some classes , so it was giving some error as output , hence it is better to either use one of them ,

Answer (score 0):

The classes you are trying to deserialize to has a few problems.
You need to make the following properties arrays:

```
 public class details
    {
    public results[] results { get; set; }
    }

   public class results
    {
        public lexicalEntries[] lexicalEntries { get; set; }
    }
    public class entries
    {
        public senses[] senses { get; set; }
    }
    public class senses
    {
       public string[] definitions { get; set; }
    }
    public class lexicalEntries
   {
     public entries[] entries { get; set; }
   }
```

I managed to deserialize your JSON object after updating the classes.
[image]

Comment: The issues has been resolved thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I prefer using dynamic and ExpandoObject can help you a lot

```c#
using System.Dynamic;
dynamic ? obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(yourJSON);
```

**the obj has exact properties as same as your JSON at the same time it does not need to create a model from any JSON**